# Visualize 1-dimensional data in a sequential colormap

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn, colormap

I have a pandas series containing numbers ranging between 0 and 100. I want to visualise it in a horizontal bar consisting of 3 main colours.

I have tried using seaborn but all I can get is a heatmap matrix. I have also tried the below code, which is producing what I need but not in the way I need it.

```
x = my_column.values
y = x
t = x
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.scatter(x, y, c=t, cmap='brg')
ax2.scatter(x, y, c=t, cmap='brg')
plt.show()
```

What I'm looking for is something similar to the below figure, how can I achieve that using matplotlib or seaborn?

[image]

Comment: Are the values sorted, or why would you expect the figure shown?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes the values are sorted and they are float values

Comment: Could you post some example data?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this is not quite clear, however, the following would produce an image like the one shown in the question:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

x = np.linspace(100,0,101)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,1), constrained_layout=True)

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["limegreen", "gold", "crimson"])
ax.imshow([x], cmap=cmap, aspect="auto", 
          extent=[x[0]-np.diff(x)[0]/2, x[-1]+np.diff(x)[0]/2,0,1])
ax.tick_params(axis="y", left=False, labelleft=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]